# Regarding .deb file linking with github

Tags: deb, github

So, I have successfully made a .deb file of my ROS package using bloom

The question is how can I integrate it with GitHub?

So that I can update my package in one place and the user can
directly update the package using `sudo apt update`

rather than installing the new deb file every time to update the repo or the package.

Comment: you can't. that's not how either github or debian packages work.

Comment: @cas Technically it can, but they'll have to create and sign an apt repository somewhere, then make the pubkey available and add additional steps to add the package build/sign step to the repo update... Which, if they're serious about doing this well, will have to include lengthy automated testing before accepting a commit as well.

Comment: @Shadur all of which are things that github doesn't do, that have nothing to do with github.  i.e. there's no "technically, it can".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do something similar where I have a build machine which monitors my VCS for changes, then autobuilds, and uses `dput *.changes` or `scp *.deb` to an `incoming/` directory on a server that I host.

That server runs `reprepro` and when `*.deb` files appear in that `incoming/` directory, a script runs `reprepro includedeb <suite> *.deb`.

Here's an [example tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-reprepro-for-a-secure-package-repository-on-ubuntu-14-04) on how to set that up.

Your users simply need to `apt-key add` your GPG key, and create a `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list` pointing to your repository.

Answer (score 1):

In order to do so, you're first going to have to create and host an actual apt archive.

The instructions [here](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianRepository/Setup) should explain the steps you need to take -- most of them can be automated by the software, but you'll need to be aware of them regardless.

You'll also need to sign the deb and release files, and inform your users where they can download your public key in order to verify your Release file.

*Then*, when you have all of that working, you're going to have to look into adding the 'build deb, upload deb, recreate and sign Release file' into the repo update.

All of this can be done, but it's *decidedly* nontrivial.